# Is there a way to preserve the USER on a docker base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building a Docker image from a supplied Docker image. I need to install new dependencies which require administrative privileges. The default user of the supplied image does not have administrative privileges. After I'm done, I want to change the default user back to the previous default user.

Is there a way to generically preserve the user of the base image without knowing it beforehand?

Note: I'm not asking how to inspect a docker image and find the default user outside the `Dockerfile`. I want to know if there is a way to do it within the file itself.

See example `Dockerfile` below

```
FROM supliedImage

USER root
... Perform administrative task
USER <Default user from supplied image>
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... there's no way to do it the way you'd like it but you can always use a workaround with multistage builds:

```
FROM solr:alpine as build

RUN whoami

FROM build as prepare_dependencies
USER root
RUN echo 'I am root' > /the_root_important_message

FROM build

COPY --from=prepare_dependencies /the_root_important_message /the_root_vital_message

RUN echo "now I'm $( whoami )"
RUN cat /the_root_vital_message
CMD echo 'this is a pain'
```

Somehow I'm fairly sure this is not what you're looking for...

Well, since this topic is pretty fun, I decided to attempt a different approach:

```
FROM solr:alpine as build

RUN whoami

FROM build as prepare_dependencies
USER root
RUN apk --no-cache --update add sudo \
    && echo 'ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' > /etc/sudoers

RUN echo "this is secret" > /secretfile
RUN chmod 400 /secretfile

FROM build

COPY --from=prepare_dependencies /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo
COPY --from=prepare_dependencies /usr/lib/sudo /usr/lib/sudo
COPY --from=prepare_dependencies /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers
COPY --from=prepare_dependencies /secretfile /secretfile

RUN sudo -l
RUN sudo cat /secretfile

RUN echo "now I'm $( whoami )"

RUN echo "cleanup" \
    && sudo rm -rf \
        /etc/sudoers /secretfile \
        /usr/lib/sudo /usr/bin/sudo

CMD echo 'this is a pain'
```

Comment: You're right that it won't fit my goal; but, it is definitely a clever solution for a simpler case.

Comment: well, I added an alternative approach. it is still horrible but somehow I like it better...

Comment: Realized I never accepted this. It's unfortunate that the answer was no, but I appreciate your attempted workaround.